# Call JSON data that has double brackets on TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following data in json:

```
[
{
id: 10033,
title: {
rendered: "My title"
},
content: {
rendered: "Sample text html",
}
}
```

My structure for this data is the following:

```
// Create structer of Post
struct JsonSosTalleres : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let title : Title?
    let content : Content?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case content = "content"
    }

}


struct Title : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}

struct Content : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}
```

I need to show this data in a table, I have two outlets: `titlePost` (label) y `contentPost`

All right but my problem is when it comes to calling the data in the cell, I have trouble calling the JSON data because it has double brackets.

```
private var getData = [DownloadJson]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DownloadJson()

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tablaView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ofertcell") as? OfertasTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

       // How do I define my code here to call the title?
        cell.titlePost.text = getData[indexPath.row].title

        return cell

    }

    // funtion get json ()

     func DownloadJson()  {
     .....
     }
```

How do I define my code here to call the title?

With the following I get an error "Can not assign value of type 'Title?' to type 'String?' "
`cell.titlePost.text = getData[indexPath.row].title`
Also tried with the following: `cell.titlePost.text = getData.Title[indexPath.row].rendered` But I have not been successful, I would appreciate if you can guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cell.titlePost.text = getData[indexPath.row].title
```

to

```
cell.titlePost.text = getData[indexPath.row]?.title?.rendered
```

Comment: If you know that the JSON really looks like this always, it would be better to remove the `?` from all your types.